# How to query with a minimum condition?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to select the name of an employee who has the earliest SDate. I tried the following:

```
SELECT [name]
          FROM [employee]
          where [dept] in ('Finance', 'HR', 'IT')
          and [SDate] = min([SDate]);
```

I was thrown with an error. Not surprising, since I had an aggregation function in the where clause. So, I modified it to this:

```
SELECT [name]
          FROM [employee]
          where [dept] in ('Finance', 'HR', 'IT')
          group by [name]
          having [SDate] = min([SDate]);
```

But it still doesn't work. How should I construct my T-SQL so that I can get the name of the employee who has the minimum SDate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @minDate Date
SELECT
    @mindate=MIN(sDate) 
FROM 
    employee E
WHERE 
    [dept] IN ('Finance', 'HR', 'IT');

SELECT
    [name]
FROM
    [employee]
WHERE
    [dept] IN ('Finance', 'HR', 'IT')
    and [sDate] = @minDate;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `order by` and `top`:

```
SELECT top 1 [name]
FROM [employee]
WHERE [dept] in ('Finance', 'HR', 'IT')
ORDER BY sdate desc;
```